# Which dependency to be used for Cassandra DB (Reactive)

Tags: cassandra, spring-webflux, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

My application is Spring Reactive based and I need to start using Cassandra DB (v 3.11.6).

Initially I have done my DB requirement by adding **spring-data-cassandra** and it was able to write DB routines using *ReactiveCassandraTemplate* as well.

But recently while searching in Net I just came to know that, there is one more dependency named **spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive** is there for Cassandra DB.

So now the confusion is that, which one I have to use in my case and what is the difference between these two dependencies

- **spring-data-cassandra**
- **spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive**

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at *mvnrepository.com* at the [spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive/2.3.0.RELEASE)

You will notice that `spring-data-cassandra` is a compile dependency of `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive` repository.

Also you will notice that `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive` has a compile dependency on `reactor-core`.

So if you are using `spring webflux` it will automatically drag in `reactor-core` for you, that's why by just dragging in `spring-data-cassandra` it will work anyway.

So that's the difference.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Andolf, so in my case I should use 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive' as it is on top or parent to spring-data-cassandra and reactor-core. right..?

Comment: What im saying is that to avoid any problems use the reactive version.